# Matlab - How to read in an image from a directory

Tags: image, matlab

I want to open a directory so that any image can be selected and then read it in using imread.

```
I have tried this:

[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the image file');
i=imread ( [FileName,PathName]);
```

But I select img3 in the directory, I get the error:

```
"img3.jpg does not exist"
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `[FileName,PathName]`, this is not a proper file name. Use `fullfile` to concatinate `PathName` and `FileName`